# programmers back-up methods and tools

Tags: backup-strategies

yesterday just happened. A tired user(me) had the bad inspiration to reinstall xampp with overrwite option. Even if I've specified that I wish to preserve htdocs and mysql\data folders, the setup didn't listen to me.

I've decided to use a back-up method from now on. Which are the tools and the good practices used by programmers in the industry?

Answer (score 0):

I [svn](http://tortoisesvn.net/) everything for my working files on an outer server or a hosting website like this http://www.assembla.com/